# Adding class to an element using jQuery + simultaneously sending custom values of css class parameters

Tags: jquery, css

I don't know if this is possible but will try to explain what I need.

I want to do something like this ....

CSS class with undefined variables X,Y,Z:

```
.r {border-radius:Xpx;-webkit-border-radius:Ypx;-moz-border-radius:Zpx;}
```

Then in body:

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

Script:

```
$("#test").addClass("r(10,10,10)")
```

As you see I have a CSS class but there are no numbers. Just variables.
And I want to apply this class to element using jquery and send all variables through jquery.
Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Thanks for editing my post Shadow Wizard :)

Comment: It's a clever idea, but this is not possible using standard CSS. It's what CSS precompilers like LESS add for static CSS resources. I don't know of any Javascript based solution to do this (although there may well be a jQuery plugin).

Comment: No problem @David, that's part of our role - to show the newcomers around. Hope the code formatting is now clear? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting idea, but unfortunately not possible to implement directly: the CSS is "compiled" instantly so such CSS is just invalid and won't be recognized.

Instead, what you can do is have such code:

```
$("#test").css({ "border-radius": "10px", "-webkit-border-radius": "10px", "-moz-border-radius": "10px" });
```

To set the CSS properties on the fly with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I knew this method but was hoping to negotiate with css only by class names and parameters values. Anyway Thanks for help. Hope something will change in future :)

Comment: Cheers @David - hard to believe something will change, but you can set different classes for different cases and set proper class e.g. `$("#test").addClass("r10");` in your original case or `$("#test").addClass("r5");` when it's `5px` instead. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, will think about it, I mean the best way to solve my issue :)